# Git compare missies files in target branch, takes all code of source branch as new

Tags: git, compare, diff

After code changes, I'm trying to create a code review from GIT webpage. Source branch is my dev branch, and target branch is my master branch. But the diff seems to be ignoring all code of master branch, taking every single line of dev branch as new.

Tried this again in git webpage compare, same problem.

I tried `git diff master..dev file1.py` in my local laptop command, and this is displaying my changes properly.

After some search, it seems like that in GIT web view, it is comparing the diff with latest common ancestor, not with the latest code in both master and dev. GIT rebase seems to be resolving this issue. But is there any other way to handle this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like there's an EOL format change going on.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what web interface you're using, but I'm going to presume it's GitHub for now.  On GitHub, the default comparison does a diff with the three-dot operator `...`, not the two-dot operator `..`.

When you do a comparison with `git diff master..dev` (two dots), it shows the differences between `master` and `dev`.  When you do a comparison with `git diff master...dev` (three dots), it takes the symmetric differences, which is the range of commits reachable from either side but not both.  That's why it looks like you're comparing against the latest common ancestor: because that's the merge base and you are.  If you want to do two-dot comparison, you can edit the URL.

If you're interested in learning more, you can see the `gitrevisions(7)` manual page, and [GitHub also has documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons).

Comment: The web interface is an internal tool, and I think it is GitLab. From the URL, it is 3-dot diff. When I modified the url to just two dot, it says ```The page could not be found or you don't have permission to view it```

Comment: GitLab [doesn't support that](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/1953).  You'll have to do that from the command line.